# Text overlaying image with center center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center center text overlaying an image. Here's what my code is:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="safaripreview">
        <img src="img/safari1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        <h3>Our String Of Pearls</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS is currently

```
.safaripreview
{
  position: relative; 
}

.safaripreview h3
{
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white; 
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

This is producing:

[image]

when i want to achieve this

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve this? Flexbox?

Comment: You can use the image as background and that way you don't need an absolute position for the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. flexbox

```css
.safaripreview {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.safaripreview {
  display: inline-block;
}
.safaripreview h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="safaripreview">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" class="img-responsive" alt="">
  <h3>Our String Of Pearls</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Just added this, works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 30px;
left: 30px;

transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Will achieve this for you.

You could also do:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;

align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

display: flex;
```

But this has less support and obviously more lines :)

Comment: I added that and it got this:
http://s32.postimg.org/5cxak69v9/screenshot_212.png

Appears to be off center on both axis

Comment: Second one worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

change css this way

```
.safaripreview h3
{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  color: white; 
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```